# How to execute sas program encoded with BASE64?

Tags: bash, file-io, sas, base64

Is it possible to execute a SAS program which would be encoded in BASE64.

Something like:

```
data _null_;
    file STDOUT;
    put "Hello World!";
run;
```

would be

`ZGF0YSBfbnVsbF87CiAgICBmaWxlIFNURE9VVDsKICAgIHB1dCAiSGVsbG8gV29ybGQhIjsKcnVuOw==`

and then execution could be done this way:

`sas < <ENCODED-SAS-PROGRAM>`

instead of
`sas hello.sas`

Basically, I need to run a SAS program, but I don't want to store it physically.

Comment: What operating system ?

Comment: The operating system is IBM AIX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recall (from HPUX days) SAS in Unix like systems had special processing for SAS option:

- `-SYSIN <sas code filename>`
  A `-` for filename would mean to read the program from stdin.

If that is the case you can try

```
echo ...base64.encoded.sas.source.code... | base64 -decode | sas -sysin -
```

Use other options to control the SAS session and additional pipe or redirects to handle STDOUT content generated by your SAS code.

Comment: The command line option you are look for is `-stdio`. The `-sysin` option is just another way of passing in the program name.  So `sas -sysin xx.sas` is the same as `sas xx.sas`.  I think `sysin` comes from the old JCL days when that was the DDNAME used for the source code.

Comment: That's really interesting, I'll try it now. base64 command isn't available on the system, but I can use a perl module to get the same result. Thanks!

Comment: So it doesn't work for me, but that's a good start. Running `echo ZGF0YSBfbnVsbF87CiAgICBmaWxlIFNURE9VVDsKICAgIHB1dCAiSGVsbG8gV29ybGQhIjsKcnVuOw== | perl -MMIME::Base64 -ne 'printf "%s\n",decode_base64($_)' | sas -sysin -` gives me the following error:

ERROR: OPTION SYSIN REQUIRES AN ARGUMENT

Comment: Per @Tom try using the `-stdio` instead of `-sysin`, docs at https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=hostunx&docsetTarget=n00se9h5vrwqrbn1uu4nb0yysmdl.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

Comment: If you've got any clue on how to redirect the response to stdout rather than a physical sas file I'm interested